# Inserting data into a Table row using Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I am currently learning about django orm and playing with this structure

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Artist:"+self.artist + " Title:"+self.title

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album) #Link to primary key in Album
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I made an entry into Album using this

> > a = Album(artist="Madonna",title="SomeTitle",genre="pop")
> >     a.save()

and that saved it.

Now how can i insert into the Song table? 
I got the previous entry like this

> > a = Album.objects.get(artist__iexact="Madonna")

One way I think I could do is this

```
   >> s = Song(a,title="SongA")
   >> s.save() #Error TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Album'
```

How can I save a song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get an instance of saved object by

```
  model_obj = Album.objects.get(artist ="Madona")
```

and after getting an object you can create Song object and save it.

```
  song_obj = Song(album=model_obj, title="SongA")
  song_obj.save()
```

Comment: Cant i get an instance of the object using ` >> a = Album.objects.get(artist__iexact="madonna")` ?

Comment: @jamesFranco yes you can but be sure in that case spellings must be correct as you are doing exact matching.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key needs the pk of the object. Use `a.id` instead of `a`.

Comment: I get `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: music_song.album_id` with `a.id`